# Refer to cell in adjacent table column in VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make a function in Excel VBA that refers to an adjacent cell within the same table and on the same row that the function would be in. Essentially, I am trying to figure out a VBA term to express the following regular Excel table reference:

`[@[columnname]]`

I only need to use this reference for a basic `IF` statement.

I feel like the answer to this problem should be glaringly obvious, but I just can't figure this one out.

[image of dummy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZKsw.png)
Edit: added this image to show what i want to do. I basically want to create a more specified if statement that will check if the value in the cell of the same row as PIK or Interest accrued (but in the Action Type column) is "Initial Set up." this is a dumbed down version but I just need to understand the concept of how to make the reference.

Edited response code (thanks btw) to fit my needs:

```
`Function IfAdvance(ifTrue As Variant, ifFalse As Variant)

Dim c As Range, lo As ListObject, f As Range

Set c = Application.Caller 'or Application.ThisCell
                           ' = the cell containing the formula

For Each lo In c.Worksheet.ListObjects
    If Not Intersect(c, lo.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

        'locate the column header of interest
        Set f = lo.HeaderRowRange.Find("Action Type", , xlValues, xlWhole)

        If f.Value = "Initial Set-Up" Then
            MyTableUDF = ifTrue
        Else
            MyTableUDF = ifFalse
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
Next lo

MyTableUDF = "Not in a Table!"

End Function`
```

but wasn't able to make it work unfortunately.

Comment: `OFFSET()`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Offset won't work because I want to be able to use it in any column of this table. I have tried to work around this by coming up with ways to reference the necessary cell address but that's sloppy and I can't get it to work as a function.

Comment: you want to see cells(activecell.row,activecell.column+1)?

Comment: You can use `offset()` in VBA though. It's not at all clear, however, what you are trying to do. Please share some sample data, and what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Would help a lot to show some dummy data and explain what you want your formula to do.

Comment: made a quick edit to show you  a version of a table I am working on, but there really isn't much complexity because I am tasked with making excel tools that non code-friendly people can understand

Comment: I can't use offset() because I want to be able to call this same function from any column of the table and have it look to a single column for reference without having to create multiple custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you want to do, but here's an example which sounds similar to your description

```
Function MyTableUDF()

    Dim c As Range, lo As ListObject, f As Range

    Set c = Application.Caller 'or Application.ThisCell
                               ' = the cell containing the formula

    For Each lo In c.Worksheet.ListObjects
        If Not Intersect(c, lo.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

            'locate the column header of interest
            Set f = lo.HeaderRowRange.Find("Col2", , xlValues, xlWhole)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                MyTableUDF = c.EntireRow.Cells(f.Column) / 2 'for example
            Else
                MyTableUDF = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next lo

    MyTableUDF = "Not in a Table!"

End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, but I edited it and couldn't make it work. Can I ask what the intersect statement means in this context?

Comment: It's a generic approach which doesn't require you to supply the table name.

Comment: ...was my best-guess at the time for what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the only concept that I really needed to know was application.caller . From there I was able to figure out the current row and tie that back to a specific column. Thanks to everyone who took the time!!

```
Function IfInitialSetup(ifTrue As Variant, ifFalse As Variant)

Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim str As String

rownum = Application.Caller.row
colnum = Sheet3.Range("Table14[Action Types]").Column
str = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(rownum, colnum).Address).Value

If str = "Initial Set-Up" Then
    IfInitialSetup = ifTrue
    Else
    IfInitialSetup = ifFalse
End If

End Function
```